# Are clickable Category Badges good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

Im running a wp magazine with a lot of posts (over 50 post) on the front-,category- and archive page.

Each thumb and title are linking to the single-post and some posts are additonally showing up the excerpt. I can turn on / off each clickable category badge near the post title. Each page, contains a lot of posts with the same category.

For better understanding what im trying to describe, please have a look to the images below the text.

**My Question:**

Are the clickable category badges good or bad for SEO?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most themes/framework do this to improve internal linking. In this way when the search engine crawler visits the above page, for example, it will have direct access to visit those category pages too and thus continue to visit the posts in these categories, and so on.

To answer your question: Yes, I think these above clickable categories are good for SEO. For one, the reason I said above but from a user point of view too.

Answer (score 1):

Having internal links increases visibility for your pages. Crawlers will be able to get to your content quicker and also create vital links between the category and the content.

I think this definitely has an impact on SEO, now how we quantify that impact is another question entirely.